# how to return an array and its length in java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

i want to return a array and its length from a method in java, where the array is of type double and length is type integer,plz help
 suppose this example-:

```
double ar={2.3,4.5,6.7};
 int len=ar.length();
```

now i am supposed to return both the array "ar" and the variable "len".
i tried this code can someone tell me the modification i need to do in the class so as to be able to return the required elements-:

```
 import java.util.List;
     public class Pair
     {
      private List<Double> array1;
    private List<Double> array2;
    public Pair(List<Double> array1, List<Double> array2)
    {
        this.array1 = array1;
        this.array2 = array2;

    }
    public List<Double> getArray1() { return array1; }
    public List<Double> getArray2() { return array2; }
}
```

Comment: what about just returning an array...? you can get length from that array..

Comment: 1. `array != arraylist`. 2. `double ar={2.3,4.5,6.7}; int len=ar.length();` will not work. 3. You can add another method which would return the length of the array or arraylist. 4. Just use the `length` property or `size()` instead of having a method do this.

Comment: Braces forgotten in `double[] ar = {2.3,4.5,6.7};`.

Comment: In Java you can return only a single object. Either return the array and get its length or create a type with the required attributes to return the object.

Comment: Hey mate i didn't got your question plz can u explane more

Comment: why you cant just call `length` on array or `size()` if you use list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the array alone and in the calling method get the array or if you want the length using the array attribute name get its length as follows length array.length()

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Pair instance = new Pair();
    int length = instance.getArray().length;
    double[] arrayValue = instance.getArray();

}



public double[] getArray()     
{
    double[] st ={1.0,2.0};
    return st; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Shekhar stated, the array length is already stored in the array. Also, the code you provided does not what you say you want do do it.

Try

```
public class Pair {
    private double[] ar;
    private int length; 

    Pair(double[] ar) {
        this.ar[] = ar;
        this.length = ar.length;
    }

    public double[] getArray() {
        return this.ar;
    }

    public double getLength() {
        return this.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return more than one value then you can just create another class and embed to values into it viz whole array and length and then return the class itself.

```
class temp
{
List<Double> array1;
int length;
}

public class Pair
{
private List<Double> array1;
private List<Double> array2;
temp t2 = new temp();
temp t1 = new temp();

public Pair(List<Double> array1, List<Double> array2)
{
t1.array1 = array1;
t1.length = array1.length;

t2.array1 = array2;
t2.length = array2.length;
}

public temp getArray1() { return t1; }
public temp getArray2() { return t2; }    
}

class temp
{
List<Double> array1;
int length;
}

public class Pair
{
private List<Double> array1;
private List<Double> array2;
temp t2 = new temp();
temp t1 = new temp();

public Pair(List<Double> array1, List<Double> array2)
{
     t1.array1 = array1;
     t1.length = array1.length;
     t2.array1 = array2;
     t2.length = array2.length;
}

public temp getArray1() { return t1; }
public temp getArray2() { return t2; }    
}


I dont know this code will work for sure or not but you can use the concept.
And other way is you can just declare the array itself globally. 


Thanks
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in a Map and return the map.

```
double [] arr = {2.3,1.2,4.5};

Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map.put("array", arr);
map.put("arrayLength", arr.length);

return map;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return a single object or array. if you want length of array you can use array.size(); after get array from your function !